# Esconder respuesta al hacer click en pregunta (sólo a la que se ha clickeado y no todas al mismo tiempo)

Tags: jquery, html5

acudo a ustedes con este problema, tal vez un tanto absurdo, pero al cual no he encontrado alguna solución del todo clara, tengo lo siguiente:
Una sección de preguntas y respuesta en las que al clickear la pregunta, deberá aparecer la respuesta de la misma, me gustaría que eso sólo sucediera con la pregunta que se está clickeando y no con todas al mismo tiempo como mi código lo hace ahora, ¿alguna idea de qué es lo que necesito para lograrlo?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var question = $(".question"),
    answer = $(".answer");
  question.click(function() {
    answer.toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="...">
  <h3>Preguntas y respuestas</h3>
  <h4 class="question">Pregunta 1</h4>

  <p class="answer"> respuesta 1</p>

  <h4 class="question">Pregunta 2</h4>

  <p class="answer"> respuesta 2</p>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi, encontrando el siguiente `.answer`de la respuesta clickada

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".question").click(function() {
$(this).find( "+ .answer" ).toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="...">
  <h3>Preguntas y respuestas</h3>
  <h4 class="question">Pregunta 1</h4>

  <p class="answer"> respuesta 1</p>

  <h4 class="question">Pregunta 2</h4>

  <p class="answer"> respuesta 2</p>


</div>
```

Comment: te agradezco bastante, justo ahora iba a comenzar con eso ! :)